# Sitecore 301 redirect module IIS error 0x800703e9

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, redirect, sitecore

I am new to .NET and Sitecore everything was fine I was getting use to Sitecore and the way it works, then I decided to install the [301 redirect module](https://github.com/thecadams/301RedirectModule/tree/master/source), I did some research and the error seems to be cause by stack overflow and all my redirects receive this error in a 500 page:

```
**Detailed Error Information**
------------------------------
        Module ManagedPipelineHandler

        Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler    
        Handler ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0  
        Error Code  0x800703e9
```

my regex pattern is formatted like this:

```
/([^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$)
```

The patch for my item is like `/Home/solutions/exemple` which is supposed to send: `www.mysite.com/en/exemple`

my solution is running in asp.net 4.0 and Sitecore 7 and I have two version EN and FR.

Any Idea how I can fix this error or someone who ran in a similar issue?

ps: How can I delete the redirect from this module because even when I delete them they are still active.

Comment: If you have deleted an item in the master and you want to remove it from the web, then you need to publish the parent. Also: next time update your question instead of deleting and making a new one. My answer remains the same: add the source code to your solution and start debugging. You know how to do that?

Comment: I did and I didn't find anything, In my last question someone talked about maybe a language fallback was causing this any idea what meant?

Comment: I am currently working on my solution and I have one issue, I have to language on my solution EN/FR so I added both to each redirect this way Sitecore can redirect to the right langue but it always fall to one language what can cause this?